# Can Belgium suspend my German driving licence?

Tags: germany, netherlands, eu, belgium

I have a German driving licence, I live in the Netherlands, and I was driving very fast in Belgium last weekend.

Can Belgium suspend my driving licence or they can only ban me from driving in Belgium?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have read this answer before posting my, but it didn't clarify what I am interested in.